# How to create increment 2D array in python

Tags: python, list

- How to create increment 2D list
- if input = 3 then output is

```
  [ 1,0,0],
  [1,2, 0],
  [1,2,3]]
```

- if input = 4 then output is

```
[[1,0,0,0],
[1,2,0,0],
[1,2,3,0], 
[1,2,3,4]]
```

Code is below to print every number to Zero

- How to increment of [x][y]

```
w = 3
matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(w)] 
matrix
```

or

```
rows = 3
cols = 3

matrix = []
for i in range(rows):
  row = []
  for j in range(cols):
    row.append(0)
  matrix.append(row)

print(matrix)
```

Comment: These are *not arrays* they are *lists*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with a list comprehension:

```
matrix = [[x + 1 for x in range(y + 1)] + [0] * (w - y - 1) for y in range(w)]
print(matrix)
```

Output for 3:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Output for 4:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

If you want to edit the value of this list in the future, use:

```
matrix = [[x + 1 for x in range(y + 1)] + [0 for x in range(w - y - 1)] for y in range(w)]
```

Because multiplying a list creates unexpected modifications for modifying.

More about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

**Edit:**

If you don't want a list comprehension, try:

```
matrix = []
for y in range(w):
    l1 = []
    for x in range(y + 1):
        l1.append(x + 1)
    l1.extend([0] * (w - y - 1))
    matrix.append(l1)
```

Comment: Can you answer without list comprehension also

Comment: @Maws Alright..

Comment: @Maws Edited my answer with a `for` loop!

Answer (score 1):

Using double-comprehension for 2D list:

```py
>>> [list(range(1, i+1))+[0]*(n-i) for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[[1, 0], [1, 2]] #n=2
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 3]]  #n=3
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4]] #n=4
```

Non-comprehension solution:

```py
result = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    row = list(range(1, i+1))+[0]*(n-i)
    result.append(row)
```

Comment: Just a note that using `*` multiplication of lists will result in unexpected modifications if you modify this list, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) out for more.

Comment: @U12-Forward no, this won't matter here.

Comment: @U12-Forward, Thank you for that reference, yes that's `True` because all the values have the same memory reference in that question. But I don't think that should be problem in this case.

Comment: Can you answer without list comprehension also

Comment: @Maws, you should not have problem to break above comprehension to normal for loop block.